# Python Dataframe find row value which changes every 10 percent

Tags: python, dataframe, row, calculated-columns

i have a Dataframe which has a column like (0.12,0.14,0.16,0.13,0.23,0.25,0.28,0.32,0.33), I want to have a new column that only record the value change more than 0.1 or -0.1. And other values remain same when changes.

so the new column should be like (0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.23,0.23,0.23,0.32,0.32)

Anyone knows how to write in a simple way?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: When values changes to 0.23, the values behind is compare to 0.23 not 0.12, and then 0.32 .....

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve with this by rounding the data to arbitrary numbers. You might want to consider either `round` function to midpoint, or using `ceil`ing/`floor` function after multiplying the array by 10.

What you're trying to achieve however can be done like this:

```
import numpy as np

def cookdata(data):
    #Assuming your data is sorted as per example array in your question
    data = np.asarray(data)
    i = 0
    startidx = 0
    while np.unique(data).size > np.ceil((data.max()-data.min())/0.1):
        lastidx = startidx + np.where(data[startidx:] < np.unique(data)[0]+0.1*(i+1))[0].size
        data[startidx:lastidx] = np.unique(data)[i]
        startidx = lastidx
        i += 1
    return data
```

This returns a dataset as asked in your question. I am sure there are better ways to do it:

```
data = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0.12, 0.5, 10))
data
array([ 0.12959374,  0.14192312,  0.21706382,  0.27638412,  0.27745105,
        0.28516701,  0.37941334,  0.4037809 ,  0.41016534,  0.48978927])

cookdata(data)
array([ 0.12959374,  0.12959374,  0.12959374,  0.27638412,  0.27638412,
        0.27638412,  0.37941334,  0.37941334,  0.37941334,  0.48978927])
```

The function returns array based on first value.

You might however want to consider simpler operations that do not require rounding values to arbitrary datapoints. Consider `np.round(data, decimals=1)`. In your case you could also use `floor` function as in: `np.floor(data/0.1)*0.1` or if you want to keep the initial value:

```
data = np.asarray(data)
datamin = data.min()
data = np.floor((data-datamin)/0.1)*0.1+datamin

data
array([ 0.12959374,  0.12959374,  0.12959374,  0.22959374,  0.22959374,
        0.22959374,  0.32959374,  0.32959374,  0.32959374,  0.42959374])
```

Here the data is as multiples of first value, rather than arbitrary value between the multiples of first value.